# multiplot cannot output binary file - how to solve

Tags: gnuplot

I have plotted some graphs exactly the same way:

[image]

Using the code:

```
set style line 1  lt 1  lw 0.9 pt 1 ps  0.9 lc  rgb "navy"
set style line 2  lt 2  lw 0.9 pt 2 ps  1.1 lc  rgb "red"
set style line 3  lt 3  lw 0.9 pt 3 ps  1.1 lc  rgb "blue"
set style line 4  lt 4  lw 0.9 pt 4 ps  1.1 lc  rgb "olive"
set style line 5  lt 5  lw 0.9 pt 5 ps  1.1 lc  rgb "black"
set style line 6  lt 6  lw 0.9 pt 6 ps  1.1 lc  rgb "gray20"

set terminal postscript eps enhanced
set encoding utf8
set multiplot
plot 'solPIhc10^0.dat' with linespoints title "{/Symbol l^2} = 10^{0}", \
'solPIhc10^1.dat' with linespoints title "{/Symbol l^2} = 10^{1}", \
'solPIhc10^-1.dat' with linespoints title "{/Symbol l^2} = 10^{-1}", \
'solPIhc10^-2.dat' with linespoints title "{/Symbol l^2} = 10^{-2}", \
'solPIhc10^-3.dat' with linespoints title "{/Symbol l^2} = 10^{-3}", \
'solPIhc10^-4.dat' with linespoints title "{/Symbol l^2} = 10^{-4}", \
'solPDhc.dat' with points ls 5 title "h1 (PD)"
set xlabel "x (m)"
set ylabel "h(W/m^2°C)"
set xrange [0:0.04]
set yrange [-500:2000]
unset multiplot
```

However, a few times my graph is correctly plotted, in other i get this annoying message

[image]

How can I overcome this?

Comment: In the above example, `multiplot` is unnecessary. Are you sure, that you want to use `multiplot`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are working in the gnuplot console and using an interactive terminal, e.g. `wxt` or `qt`, etc. for testing your script getting an immediate output in a window.
However, when you `set term postscript`, you also need to define a file via `set output` (check `help output`).

A minimal example would be (I typically start a script with `reset session`)

```
reset session
set terminal postscript eps enhanced
set output "SO76969492.eps"

plot sin(x)/x      # or whatever

set output         # close the file
```

Comment: I am using  the interactive terminal. It used to be qt, now I have chosen windows. When I do what you suggest, here it what the program shows me:

"you can't change output in multiplot mode"

Comment: @CairoMartins a postscript file .ps, .eps, or a .pdf or a .png will not directly be displayed in an interactive window but saved to a file to be looked at with another viewer. That's why you need to define an output file.

Comment: @CairoMartins type `unset multiplot` in the console or insert it at the beginning of your script before you set the terminal.

Comment: @CairoMartins Problem solved? If yes, please check the check mark at the top left of the answer indicating that the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

The correct order is:

```
set terminal postscript enhanced eps
set output 'something.eps'
set multiplot

set xlabel "x (m)"
# ...
plot 'your-file.dat'
# other plots

unset multiplot
unset output            # or set output or set output '/dev/null' or ...
set term qt             # or wxt; if you want to return to interactive mode
```

**NOTES**

- In your example, you don't have to use `multiplot`. `plot <first>, <second>, <third>...` is enough.
- You have to set the `xlabel` and others before the `plot` command.